# What is proper way to update D8 DEV?

Tags: 8

I'm not having any luck with Drush (just hangs) to update a (non-production) D8 site, dev branch (from around beta2) to Head.  How would one manually update the files db/config?

Comment: See the comment chx left in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use documentation provided by Drupal on [THIS](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!UPGRADE.txt/8) link. I'm did core upgrade by following steps from this document.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is "not".

Upgrade path is not supported and not possible.

Comment: Didn't we have a beta1 -> beta2 question about this already? I was trying to find it so we can close dup, but I can't locate it.

Comment: There were a few already yes, the last one only two days ago: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5B8%5D+upgrade+is%3Aquestion